# How can I delete a desktop file for all users with VBS?

Tags: file, vbscript, desktop, delete-file

I've searched and tried various ways of deleting a specific file on the Desktop with VBS.

<strike>My code never errors</strike> it simply just doesn't delete the file. Whether it be a Delete.txt test file or the .url and .website files I actually want removed. Below is a revised code after some help.

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
A = DesktopPath & "\Kronos Workforce Central(R).url" 
FSO.DeleteFile A
B = DesktopPath & "\Kronos Workforce Central(R).website"
FSO.DeleteFile B
```

> Line: 6
>
> Char: 1
>
> Error: File not found
>
> Code: 800A0035
>
> Source: Microsoft VBScript run time error

My computer doesn't know what FSO is? Is there another method to delete known files off desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but evidence for "no quoting of args to FSO methods":

```
>> s = DesktopPath & "\Kronos Workforce Central(R).url"
>> ss = qq(s)
>> WScript.Echo s
>> WScript.Echo ss
>> WScript.Echo FSO.FileExists(s)
>> WScript.Echo FSO.FileExists(ss)
>>
C:\Documents and Settings\eh\Desktop\Kronos Workforce Central(R).url
"C:\Documents and Settings\eh\Desktop\Kronos Workforce Central(R).url"
-1
0
```

The above should prove that the file `C:\Documents and Settings\eh\Desktop\Kronos Workforce Central(R).url` exists. This:

```
>> WScript.Echo FSO.FileExists(s)
>> FSO.DeleteFile s
>> WScript.Echo FSO.FileExists(s)
>>
-1
0
>> FSO.DeleteFile s
>>
Error Number:       53
Error Description:  File not found
```

proves that `FSO.DeleteFile <FileSpecWithNoSpuriousQuotes>` is the correct way to remove a (n existing) file and that you will get a "File not found" error when you try to zap a non-existing file.

If .DeleteFile 'does not work with no error' then you have an "On Error Resume Next" active - always a bad idea. If you didn't use OERN and got no error, then .DeleteFile removed a file - maybe you looked at the wrong desktop?